# How to minimize the aberration by aligning the objective and the eyepiece when setting up a microscopic system

Tags: optics, microscopy

I set up a microscopic system, which consists of a 1-micron pinhole as the target, an objective, an eyepiece lens and a CCD camera. However, the image I obtained contains some kind of aberration. The image of the pinhole becomes an ellipse. I have no idea of where this aberration comes from. Do you guys have any idea? Thanks a lot.

I've tried to tilt the objective and the eyepiece. The aberration reduced but was still there.

Comment: if the pinhole is off-axis then perhaps astigmatism but have a look at this website microscopyu.com/microscopy-basics and microscopyu.com/tutorials/astigmatism

Comment: Thank you hyportnex! I indeed didn't carefully make sure the pinhole was on the axis.  Do you know if there's a standard procedure that I can follow to eliminate the aberrations or determine their sources?